# Cauchy interlacing theorem - how to complete this proof

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, functional-analysis

I am looking for a proof using the min-max principle.
Wikipedia seem to provide just that: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Min-max_theorem#Cauchy_interlacing_theorem

But this part seems to be wrong:

> This can be proven using the min-max principle. Let $\beta_i$ have corresponding eigenvector $b_i$ and $S_j$ be the $j$ dimensional subspace $S_j=\operatorname{span}\{b_1,\dots, b_j\}$, then
>    $$ \beta_j = \max_{x\in S_j,\|x\|=1}(Bx,x) =\max_{x\in S_j,\|x\|=1}(PAPx,x) =\max_{x\in S_j,\|x\|=1}(Ax,x)$$

How is the shift from $PAPx$ to $Ax$ legal? $PAP$ is an $m\times m$ matrix while $A$ is an $n\times n$ matrix. $x$ can't fit both.
Can anyone correct the proof?

Comment: Hint: 
I am sure you know that $P$  is an orthogonal projection onto $S_j$. So observe that if $x\in S_j$ then $Px=x$.

Comment: But P is mxn, how can it preserve x?

Comment: Do you know what a projection is?

Comment: I know that if you project from 3 dimensions to 2 dimensions, it is impossible to have Px=x. Or am I missing something fundamental here?

Comment: ,If $P$ is $m\times n$ and $A$ is $n\times n$, how do you find $PAP$?

Comment: That's right. I believe this is another mistake in this wikipedia article. B=PAP and A are of different dimensions, so P cannot be a square matrix. I think they're missing a transpose on one of the P's

Answer (score 1):

The proof on wikipedia has many flaws indeed. The projection $P$ can be expressed with matrix $P=V*V'$ where columns of $V$ are eigenvectors $v_1, v_2, \dots v_m$ associated with $\alpha_1, \dots \alpha_m$ of $A$. So $V$ is $n*m$ matrix.
Then you can write $B=V'*A*V$ and
$\max (Bx,x) = \max x'*V'*A*V*x = \max (V*x)'*A*(V*x)$.
When $\operatorname{norm}(x)=1$ then $\operatorname{norm}(Vx)=1$ as well.
This is how I got to the end of the proof.